# Remove all files NOT containing a pattern in the contents

Tags: linux

How do I remove all files not containing a specified text.

I understand the solution to remove files with a specified text, but I need to remove files NOT containing a specified pattern.

The following command creates a list of files not containing "successful run":

```sh
grep -c "successful run" *.out | grep -v ":1" > err.txt
```

I wish to directly delete these files.

Comment: Could one single .out file log both successful and unsucessful runs?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani The right question for your case should be "could one single `.out` file contain at least one line with the pattern and at least one line without the pattern?" I can imagine there are two lines from one successful run (e.g. there's a timestamp in a separate line).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, would you please let the OP answer the question I asked? Thanks.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani My comment neither is able nor tries to stop the OP. It tries to convince you the answer you're hoping to get may not be able to support your current assumptions without additional assumption. The additional assumption is "successful run generates at most one line".

Answer (score 0):

Your original approach to identify appropriate files

> ```
> grep -c "successful run" *.out | grep -v ":1"
> ```

is flawed. Main concerns:

- What if there are two or more matching lines in one file? `grep ":0"` seems to fit the condition in the title of your question better ("files not containing a pattern").
- What if `:1` (or `:0`) is in the filename? So `grep ':0$'` seems even better.
- What if there's a newline character in any filename passed from the first `grep`?

I say do not rely on `grep -c`; rely on the exit status from `grep` which is `1` if no lines were selected.

```
for f in *.out; do
   [ -f "$f" ] && {
      grep -q -- "successful run" "$f"
      [ "$?" -eq 1 ] && rm -i -- "$f"
   }
done
```

Notes:

- `[ -f "$f" ] && …` will not let `grep` work with directories, fifos etc. that match `*.out`; only regular files.
- The meaning and significance of `--` is explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618). It's in case there's a file with name starting with `-`, it can be mistaken for an option. Another way to deal with this problem is `for f in ./*.out; do …`. This way every expanded `$f` starts with `./` so it cannot start with `-`.
- I used `rm -i` just in case. After you test the solution you may want to omit `-i`.
- `grep … || rm …` is worse. When a real error occurs (e.g. permission denied) the exit status of `grep` is greater than `1`; you probably don't want to remove the file then. My solution tests if the exit status is exactly `1`.
- Your original code doesn't descend into subdirectories, neither does mine. If you want recursion then a shell that supports it (e.g. Bash with `shopt -s globstar` and `**`) or a solution based on `find` will be useful.

Answer (score -1):

Considering that your files have either a single "successful run" or none, then:

to find the matching files you can do:

```
grep -l "successful run" *.out > err.txt
```

to find and remove them:

```
grep -l "successful run" *.out | xargs rm
```

to find the files without match you then do:

```
grep -vl "successful run" *.out > ok.txt
```

to find and remove them:

```
grep -vl "successful run" *.out | xargs rm
```

The flags mean:

```
-l lists the files with matches
-v/--invert-match inverts the matching logic
```

Comment: -1. `grep -v` does not find "files without matches". It finds "files with lines without matches". It can be `grep -l foo` and `grep -vl foo` both print the same file because there is a line with `foo` and another line without `foo` in the file.

Comment: You are confusing lines and files. If 'foo' is in the file **anywhere** then `grep -l foo file` will list it. If is not *anywhere*, then it will be listed by `grep -vl foo file'. But feel free to come up with two files that will be simultaneously listed with `grep -vl pattern` and `grep -l pattern`. Good luck.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' foo bar > test; grep -l foo test; grep -vl foo test`. Both `grep`s will list the same file.

Comment: Because it **IS** the same file. Did you read what I wrote? "come up with _two_ _files_ that..." Good try though :)

Comment: OK. Run the same command but name the file `test2`. Now there are two files. What's your point? My point is `grep -vl…` may find files *with* matches. This is not a right way to find files totally without matches.

Comment: I think I now understand what you are getting at. My assumption (based on context) is that the file contents only have the results of one run (call it a makefile, something like that). No way to know besides asking the OP to clarify that. Should there be many runs, you'd be right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99192/discussion-between-eduardo-trapani-and-kamil-maciorowski).