# Find all files that don't contain a given string

Tags: linux, bash, grep

`grep -l "this is a test"`
will list all files in `$pwd` that contain the specified string.  But

`grep -vl "this is a test"`
will list all files including those, because those that contain that string also contain lines without that string.

I could build a list of the first group, and then list all files in the directory that are not on that list, but is there a simpler way?  I normally use `bash`, but I can switch to `csh` or even `perl` if it would help.

Comment: Compare [this](https://superuser.com/q/1486987/432690). Do you need to search in subdirectories?

Comment: Yes, but for that I can use `find … -exec …`  I’ll have to study that other—thanks.  But it looks like a one-liner version of my list idea.  Would be nice if `grep` had a command-line switch for it.

Comment: To be clear: there's my answer there. It says "rely on the exit status from `grep` which is `1` if no lines were selected".

Comment: I see that answer.  It will work, but it still isn’t “a simpler way”.   It is, however, an approach I may take.

Answer (score 1):

Fgrep -o -r -i -L string *
-o reports the file only
-r recursive into sub-directories
-i case insensitive 
-L, --files-without-match
Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been printed. The scanning will stop on the first match.

Comment: Sorry my title question was slightly different from the body.  Fixed.  First match won't work; need all of them.