# How to remove all files that do not contain specific substring?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, bulk

I have read this post: [Remove all files NOT containing a pattern in the contents](https://superuser.com/questions/1486987/remove-all-files-not-containing-a-pattern-in-the-contents) which is, if I searched right, the only question similar to mine, however it's about Linux and Grep. I'm forced to stay on **Windows** for job-related reasons.

I have a directory that has lots of files and I want to **batch-delete** all the files that **do not contain a specific substring**.

Let's say I want to delete all files that do not have a single match for "saber" string, files that do not have the word "saber" anywhere among all the lines inside. If a file without "saber" word is found, it's deleted.

How can I do that?

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: You should read **this** post: [scripting - Batch script to delete files in folder that does not contain certain word - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870235/batch-script-to-delete-files-in-folder-that-does-not-contain-certain-word) which answers your question.

Comment: [1] use `Get-ChildItem` to get a list of the files. [2] use `Select-String` to both read in each file AND to search for the target string. [3] if the string aint found, kill the file with `Remove-Item`.

Comment: Tank you guys! Too bad I can't upvote :(